# Python/OpenCV/Mac ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, macos, opencv

When I put my python code in "~/Downloads/" folder, it works.
However, I failed and gave me the message "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import" when I put the test.py file in a deep location like "/Git/Pyehon/....." Why?

I run this on Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reaseon, there is a file named time.py in the same foder. I'm sure that's the reason I failed to import numpy.

Plus, if i put the file time.py in the same folder and run python test.py, then I got the message "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Next, without closing the console, and delete the time.py, then "import numpy", I got the message "ImportError: cannot import name multiarray"

close and open the console again, it works.

But this time, I did't see "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import" ,But it does work!